# prevent access to page on small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making small web pages for fun and hosting them on my server just to learn stuff and sometimes i send them to some people i know to show them what i've learn but i'd like it so that my web pages aren't accesible to people on small screen.
i tried doing

```html
@media (max-width: 800px){
            body{
                height: 0px !important;
                width: 0px !important;
            }
        }
```

but it didn't work

Comment: _"aren't accesible to people on small screen"_ - please **never** do this

Comment: When you say "prevent access" it makes it sound like you don't want them to be allowed to view the contents of the page. CSS is not appropriate for that goal. It could be that you just want the page to be "invisible" but I just want to clarify that won't prevent access in a secure way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    html {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me, i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (max-width: 800px){
            body{
              display:none;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way to do this is using `window.innerWidth`.

You can make an onload function that checks the viewport width.

```
window.onload = () => {
   if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
   document.body.innerHTML = 'Page not accessible on small screens.'
   } else {
    loadDOM(); /* maybe put [display: none] on body as default and remove it here */
   }
}
```

This method is better for the user. Atleast they'll know that they have to access the site from a larger device

Comment: Pure CSS solution is cleaner and can also include this message.